# presario powers up but screen never lights up

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I have a Compaq laptop Presario CQ61.
The unit powers up but the screen doesn't light up.  I downloaded a Kaspersky update, rebooted and the screen had a small check mark in the upper left corner.  I turned the computer off after over an hour and turned it back on and the unit powers up but the screen is off completely.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: does the backlight come on?  does the screen show anything when the machine turns on?  like a COmpaq logo?

Answer (score 1):

When your system first boots up, it will display the "BIOS" screen to let you know that everything is working. If, when you press the power button the screen stays off, you might be facing a hardware issue. As a laptop, there is not much you can do other than contacting support to get it fixed.

Since it is a laptop, you may have a software issue that is has frozen your computer on a blank screen and set your power button to put the computer to sleep instead of turning of the machine. To force a "cold start" unplug the laptop and remove the battery. Give it 3-5 minutes to discharge (no lights on the computer) then plug it back in and turn it on. This will hopefully give you the opportunity to see the "BIOS screen" and verify that the hardware is working.